# With the GMail API, what's the preferred way to get new messages?

Tags: push-notification, gmail-imap, gmail-api

The app I'm making needs to monitor the Inbox for new messages. As far as I am aware, there is no way yet for the GMail API to push a notif to me when a user has a new message ([Push notification for new gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735662/push-notification-for-new-gmail)).

I could check every minute for new messages by using the history IDs. Is that the current best method outside of implementing a full IMAP solution (which would no longer be utilizing the GMail API)?

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient Gmail API method would be to use [history.list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list). Specify a `labelId` of Inbox (so you're not seeing updates on other labels) and a `historyId` of whatever the largest `historyId` you've previously seen is (you'll need to track this). If you get back a 404 error, you'll need to use [messages.list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) instead to perform a full sync.